# How to use jquery (or JS) to check if a conditionally included file has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, loaded

I apologize in advance that this is such a basic question (I'm a newbie), but I haven't been able to find the answer.

I'm working on a WordPress membership site that presents a full post when the visitor is a member, but when a non-member tries to view the page, a file loads ("notMember.php") that basically says "Hey, you're not a member".

I've been asked to track how many times this notMember.php is being shown on the site.

We're using Google Analytics and I want to record each load of the notMember.php as an event.

I understand how to track events in Google Analytics, but what I can't come up with is the code that basically amounts to finding out whether or not notMember.php has been loaded.

I basically want a script that says:

```
If (notMember.php has been loaded) {
    // run GA event tracking code
}
```

But I don't know how to come up with that conditional.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the GA tracking code in a `<script>` element and then put that inside `notMember.php`.